# Why I have a lot of offenses in my local project while my team mates don't have any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

We are using rubocop in our project, the problem is when I use rubocop I get 182 offenses while my team mates in the same branch don't get any, we have the same ruby, rails and rubocop version.

```
spec/rails_helper.rb:45:4: C: [Correctable] Style/FetchEnvVar: Use ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") or ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", nil) instead of ENV["RAILS_ENV"].
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "test"
```

One example of the offenses that I got.

Rubocop v: 1.28.2
rails v: 6.0.3.4
ruby v: 2.7.2

Comment: Do they have a `.rubocop.yml` that you don't have?

Comment: @muistooshort we have the same file

Comment: Are you sure you're all using the same configuration? https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html

Comment: As a complete aside and because I don't write the "style guides" I find `ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV")` and even `ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV",nil)` more offensive than `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`. Especially becuase #1 is a change of result (raises a `KeyError` rather than returning `nil`) and #2 has an identical result to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` just with more overhead.

Comment: @muistooshort we are I checked twice :/

Comment: @engineersmnky yep they don't have those offenses in their projects just me that's the weird thing.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version? `rubocop` will run what's installed on your system, `bundle exec rubocop` will run the version installed by Bundler.

Answer (score 1):

***.rubocop_todo.yml*** files filter out a list Rubocop offenses.
If your teammates have one and you do not, or if you have a different version of this file, then different offenses will be flagged by Rubocop.

https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#automatically-generated-configuration

Answer (score 0):

There are only two factors influencing rubocop: rubocop gem version and .rubocop.yml configuration.

You can run `rubocop --debug` to see more details about configuration which is used.